# Get-Content match files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I want to read in a text file and match the content data in the text file to a filename and then log the output.
This is what I have so far and it is not working:

```cs
$Source = "S:\*.*"
$Missing_Files = "C:\Temp\Powershell Scripts\Missing Files Script\Results\"

foreach ($ID in Get-Content 'C:\Temp\Powershell Scripts\Missing Files 
Script\IDS.txt') {
$ID
$Count = 0
Get-Childitem $Source -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | where {$_.name - 
notmatch $ID} | foreach {
}
if ($Count -eq 0) {
    Write-Host $_.name "No File Found"
    Write-Output $ID "No File Found" | Out-File $Missing_Files\$(Get-Date -f 
yyyy-MM-dd)_Missing_Files_Results.txt -append
    }
}
```

Comment: The code you posted is broken (wrapped incorrectly in several places). Is what you posted *exactly* how the code is in your script? If so, you need to fix the syntax errors. If not: please edit your answer and post the code *exactly* as it is in your script. You may also want to elaborate on how *exactly* the code "is not working". Describe what you expect the code to do, and also what it actually does.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to search for files that are **NOT** listed in the text file
`C:\Temp\Powershell Scripts\Missing Files Script\IDS.txt`.

Any file that is found and not listed in that file is regarded as extraneous and you want to have the script create (or append to) a results file if it found extra files or not.

In that case, This should work:

```
$SourcePath  = "S:\"
$OutputPath  = "C:\Temp\Powershell Scripts\Missing Files Script\Results"
$OutputFile  = Join-Path -Path $OutputPath -ChildPath ('{0:yyyy-MM-dd}_Missing_Files_Results.txt' -f (Get-Date))
$ListedFiles = Get-Content 'C:\Temp\Powershell Scripts\Missing Files Script\IDS.txt' | Sort-Object -Unique

# get an array of filenames that are NOT listed in 'C:\Temp\Powershell Scripts\Missing Files Script\IDS.txt'
$files = @(Get-Childitem $SourcePath -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
           Where-Object { $ListedFiles -notcontains $_.Name })

if ($files.Count) {
    # we found files that are NOT listed
    Write-Host "$($file.Count) Files found that are not listed in '$ListedFiles'"
    Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value ($files -join [Environment]::NewLine)
}
else {
    # no files found
    Write-Host "No files found"
    Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "No file found."
}
```

Hope that helps